# Column line problem in tables

Tags: tabularx, columns, line

i'm using a lot of tables in the document I'm writing and I have a problem with some column lines.
I wrote this code:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|p{13cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
\hline
Campo / Esempio & Significato / possibile contenuto (comune) \\
\hline
CON. & Destinatario (CON)\\
\hline
WMS. & Mittente (WMS)\\
\hline
1. & Nr. ordine telegramma (0-9) \\
\hline
CP. & Tipo telegramma (CP) \\
\hline
LV. & Tipo ordine (LV) \\
\hline
01.01.2000$--$. & Fonte (data, opzionale) \\
\hline
23:59$------$. & Posizione (ora, opzionale) \\
\hline
$------------$. & Destinazione ($------------$) \\
\hline
$-$. & LHD nr. ($-$) \\
\hline
$--$. & Status ($--$) \\
\hline
$-------$. & Campo informativo ($-------$) \\
\hline
I$--------$. & Codice identificativo ($--------$) \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Struttura del completamento segnali vivi}
\label{table:AliveSignalCompleteTelegram} \end{table}
```

I use tabularx because I want to put the text aligned to the left but I can't see the middle column line (beetwen the 2 columns). What's wrong with this cose?
Thank you very much.

Andrea

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: `p{4cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X` declares two adjacent columns of different  types, one is 4 cm wide and contains justified contents (`p{4cm}`), the other contains left aligned contents and is of variable width (`>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X`). Similrarly, you also declared a second set of two columns that stay unused. You probably wanted to use `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}` instead of your current definition.

Comment: Thank you, it's all clear now!

Answer (score 1):

You have declared 4 columns with a rule before the first, after the second and after the fourth, but your data only has two entries per row so the third rule is not used.

You have a column specification of

```
{
|                               % rule
p{4cm}                          % 1st column 4cm wide
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X % 2nd column, variable
|                               % rule
p{13cm}                         % 3rd column 13cm!! wide
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X % 4th column, variable
|                               % rule
}
```

As you only have two entries per row the effective column specification is

```
{
|                               % rule
p{4cm}                          % 1st column 4cm wide
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X % 2nd column, variable
|                               % rule
}
```

with a rule at the start and end but not between the two columns.

Comment: Really? Why did you say that I have declared 4 columns? I wrote just 3 vertical lines (left, middle and right vertical line), where is my mistake? Thank you

Comment: @AndreaBoldrin I added to the answer, giving more details

Comment: Ooooook, now it's all clear! I really needed an explanation about that. Thank you so much!